# Unable to retrieve firebase data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have a firebase database in the following form:

[image]

My target is to retrieve the value at the node addTag, when I have the address key with me. Here is my code:

```
val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
val userid = user?.uid
mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("users").child(userid.toString()).child("Address")
mRef.child(addkey.toString()).addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {
            }

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                val useraddtag = p0.child("addTag").getValue(String::class.java)

            }

})
```

The onDataChange function, however, is never called.

"addkey" contains the key of the particular address that is being accessed.

Comment: What *exactly* is `addkey` here?  Why do you need to call `toString()` on it, and what exactly does `toString()` return?

Comment: addkey contains the key of the address, for instance LfNDsa0mvnCCEK94XSB. This key is actually stored in another instance and passed on to this instance. If .toString() is not added I get a Type Mismatch error which says Required String, Found String?

Comment: It is retrieved as follows: var addkey = intent.getStringExtra("address")

Comment: can you put a breakpoint at that line and see if you are actually getting the value of that key ? Also, if it's an StringExtra you shouldnt be doing .toString() after addkey

Comment: The key value is correct, I have checked that. The issue possibly is the toString() as you have correctly pointed out. I have found a temporary workaround by passing the  addtag from the previous intent, instead of retrieving it here. But still would want to know the issue over here

Comment: If  you try to log the `useraddtag`, what is the output? Please responde with @AlexMamo